# Ionic CSS changes are not persistent when after ionic serve / cordova run android commands

Tags: android, css, cordova, ionic3

I am developping an app on Ionic version 3.9.2, for android tablets. I am working under windows 10 with Visual Studio Code.

In my `plaform` folder, I have only one device : my physical Android device.

The way I process to fix some CSS details is that I simply launch a
`ionic serve` command, find my HTML element, and update the main.css file located in the `www/build` folder (I am not using SCSS).

This works okay until I decide to check if everything looks good on my android tablet : I will launch a `cordova run android`, and then all the CSS changes are lost - even if I go back on my browser, and launch a new `ionic serve`.

Please note that I am talking about very basic styles, like colors and font size, not platform-specific styles.

I am not sure this behavior is because of the target device itself; it's looks like the changes will be included successfully on my testing platform until I decide to change the platform, and then the new platform will erase my changes because it's taking over the building process.

Is that possible ?

Maybe should I stop switching between those 2 commands ?

Or maybe should I edit both CSS files (www/build/main.css and platforms/android/assets/www/build/main.css) at the same time, which require a lot more work ?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `gulp` to watch changes to your CSS files. You can also forcibly refresh CSS changes by holding `SHIFT` while clicking on the refresh icon.

Comment: You should not edit any of those two css files because they are generated when you run a build command, thats why your changes get lost. All development happens in the `src` folder. You should go through a few basic tutorials to get familiar with hybrid app development.

Answer (score 0):

Oh of course, I shouldn't edit this CSS file.
Instead, edit the right SCSS file inside the SRC folder.

Thanks for your answer.